# Visual Studio region folding the same format for php storm

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is their a plugin in VS Code for folding a region with a format of  like in php storm?
Example format:

**// region title**

```
  Code here
```

**// endegion title**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can!

You can use:

```
//region region-desc
   Code here
//endregion
```

Refer to this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12207)!